# scikit-learn SGDClassifier warm start ignored

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm trying to use SGDClassifier from scikit-learn version 0.15.1. There doesn't appear to be any way to set convergence criteria other than number of iterations. So I'd like to do that manually by checking the error at each iteration, then warm-starting additional iterations until the improvements are sufficiently small.

Unfortunately neither the warm_start flag nor coef_init/intercept_init seem to actually warm-start the optimization -- they both seem to start from scratch.

What should I do? Without a real convergence criterion or a warm start, the classifier isn't usable.

Notice below how the bias increases a lot on each restart, and how the loss also increases but comes down with further iterations. After 250 iterations the bias is -3.44 and average loss is 1.46.

```
sgd = SGDClassifier(loss='log', alpha=alpha, verbose=1, shuffle=True, 
                    warm_start=True)
print('INITIAL FIT')
sgd.fit(X, y, sample_weight=sample_weight)
sgd.n_iter = 1
print('\nONE MORE ITERATION')
sgd.fit(X, y, sample_weight=sample_weight)
sgd.n_iter = 3
print('\nTHREE MORE ITERATIONS')
sgd.fit(X, y, sample_weight=sample_weight)


INITIAL FIT
-- Epoch 1
Norm: 254.11, NNZs: 92299, Bias: -5.239955, T: 122956, Avg. loss: 28.103236
Total training time: 0.04 seconds.
-- Epoch 2
Norm: 138.81, NNZs: 92598, Bias: -5.180938, T: 245912, Avg. loss: 16.420537
Total training time: 0.08 seconds.
-- Epoch 3
Norm: 100.61, NNZs: 92598, Bias: -5.082776, T: 368868, Avg. loss: 12.240537
Total training time: 0.12 seconds.
-- Epoch 4
Norm: 74.18, NNZs: 92598, Bias: -5.076395, T: 491824, Avg. loss: 9.859404
Total training time: 0.17 seconds.
-- Epoch 5
Norm: 55.57, NNZs: 92598, Bias: -5.072369, T: 614780, Avg. loss: 8.280854
Total training time: 0.21 seconds.

ONE MORE ITERATION
-- Epoch 1
Norm: 243.07, NNZs: 92598, Bias: -11.271497, T: 122956, Avg. loss: 26.148746
Total training time: 0.04 seconds.

THREE MORE ITERATIONS
-- Epoch 1
Norm: 258.70, NNZs: 92598, Bias: -16.058395, T: 122956, Avg. loss: 29.666688
Total training time: 0.04 seconds.
-- Epoch 2
Norm: 142.24, NNZs: 92598, Bias: -15.809559, T: 245912, Avg. loss: 17.435114
Total training time: 0.08 seconds.
-- Epoch 3
Norm: 102.71, NNZs: 92598, Bias: -15.715853, T: 368868, Avg. loss: 12.731181
Total training time: 0.12 seconds.
```

Comment: Have you tried to use partial_fit() instead of fit() ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`warm_start=True` will use the fitted coefficients as starting points but it re-starts the learning rate schedule.

If you want to manually check for convergence I suggest you use `partial_fit` instead of `fit` as @AdrienNK suggested:

```
sgd = SGDClassifier(loss='log', alpha=alpha, verbose=1, shuffle=True, 
                warm_start=True, n_iter=1)
sgd.partial_fit(X, y)
# after 1st iteration
sgd.partial_fit(X, y)
# after 2nd iteration
...
```

Comment: Does SGD use n_iter variable for partial_fit. When I track loss, I notice that It always show Epoch 1. So even if I set n_iter to 5, with partial_fit it only go over the data once. Is that an expected behavior?